# Calculation of Christoffel symbol for unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

We use the following parameterisation for the unit sphere: $\sigma(\theta,\phi)=(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta)$.
I have calculated the Christoffel symbols to be 
$\Gamma^1_{11}=\Gamma^2_{11}=\Gamma^1_{12}=0, \Gamma^1_{22}=\sin\theta\cos\theta,\Gamma^2_{22}=0$, which match the answers I am given in my notes. But when I calculate $\Gamma^2_{12}$ I get $-\sin\theta\cos\theta$, which apparently is incorrect and should be $-\tan\theta$. My reasoning was that $\Gamma^2_{12}=\sigma_\phi \cdot \sigma_{\theta\phi}=(-\cos\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\cos\phi,0)\cdot(\sin\theta\sin\phi,-\sin\theta\cos\phi,0)=-\sin\theta\cos\theta$. I am not sure what I am doing wrong - the same method worked for the other five symbols and I have no idea where a $\tan\theta$ term would come from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Your calculation, as you've shown it, looks correct. When you use it to compute the curvature of the sphere, do you get $1$? What if you use the alternative ($-\tan \theta$)? Perhaps *your* answer is the correct one. Also: I didn't try to answer this question in part because I don't recognize the notation using $\sigma$s (even though I've taught diff'l geom courses once or twice). Amplifying your question with details about the notation, and showing the earlier parts of the computation, might be helpful to others.

Comment: @JohnHughes I was not aware that Christoffel symbols were so often defined with matrices, so yes I should make my definition clear. Here the Christoffel symbols are defined to be the respective coefficients of $\sigma_u,\sigma_v,N$ in $\sigma_{uu},\sigma_{uv},\sigma_{vv}$ (where $N$ is the unit normal to the surface). So in particular, $\Gamma^2_{12}$ is the coefficient of $\sigma_v$ in $\sigma_{uv}$ (expressed in terms of the basis $\sigma_u,\sigma_v,N$). Perhaps they made a mistake, but that would seem strange considering that I see $-\tan\theta$ elsewhere, including the answer given below.

Comment: Aha, I've realised my mistake was that I implicitly assumed the basis was orthonormal in my calculation when it is obviously not in general. Very stupid mistake. So that is why the much more complicated method with matrices is used... (It is rather amusing though that in this case the basis happened to be orthogonal so my method actually works in this case if one remembers to 'normalise' at the end.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
You can directly calculate the metric coefficients for this parameterization as ($x^1 = \cos\theta, x^2 = \phi$)

$$
(g_{\mu\nu}) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos^2\theta} ~~~\mbox{and}~~
(g^{\mu\nu}) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/\cos^2\theta}
$$

From this is pretty straightforward to calculate $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$

$$
\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\lambda\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\mu\alpha}}{\partial x^{\nu}}+ \frac{\partial g_{\alpha\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}   - \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)
$$

Take $\lambda = 2$, $\mu = 1$ and $\nu = 2$

\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma^{2}_{12} &=& \frac{1}{2}g^{2\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial g_{1\alpha}}{\partial x^{2}}+ \frac{\partial g_{\alpha2}}{\partial x^{1}} - \frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}g^{22}\left(\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}} + \frac{\partial g_{22}}{\partial x^{1}} - \cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial g_{12}}{\partial x^{2}}}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}\right) \frac{\partial \cos^2\theta}{\partial  \theta} = -\tan\theta
\end{eqnarray}

You can calculate the other components the same way

$$
\Gamma_{11}^1 = \Gamma_{11}^2 = \Gamma_{12}^1 = \Gamma_{22}^2 = 0
$$

and

$$
\Gamma_{22}^1 = \sin\theta\cos\theta
$$

Answer (score 1):

There's another way, and I think this is what you were going for in your post, but is is completely equivalent to my other answer, the idea is to calculate

$$
\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \sigma^\alpha}\frac{\partial^2 \sigma^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} \tag{1}
$$

You can obtain the inverse mapping fairly easily

$$
\theta = \arcsin \sigma^2 \equiv x^1 ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \phi = \arctan \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^1}\right) \equiv x^2 \tag{2}
$$

With this we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma^{2}_{12} &=& \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial \sigma^\alpha} \frac{\partial^2 \sigma^\alpha}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2} \\
&=& \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial \sigma^1} \frac{\partial^2 \sigma^1}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2} + \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial \sigma^2} \frac{\partial^2 \sigma^2}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2} + \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial \sigma^3} \frac{\partial^3 \sigma^1}{\partial x^1 \partial x^2} \\
&=& -\frac{\sigma^2 \sin\theta\sin\phi}{(\sigma^1)^2 + (\sigma^2)^2}-\frac{\sigma^1\sin\theta\cos\phi}{(\sigma^1)^2 + (\sigma^2)^2} \\
&=& - \tan\theta \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}